# Minimax for simple running sum game

Tags: c#, minimax

Trying to implement minimax for a game where player's alternate adding one or two to a total until it hits 21. The player to increase the total to 21 wins.

I'm using the following psueodocode:

```
01 function minimax(node, depth, maximizingPlayer)
02     if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node
03         return the heuristic value of node

04     if maximizingPlayer
05         bestValue := −∞
06         for each child of node
07             v := minimax(child, depth − 1, FALSE)
08             bestValue := max(bestValue, v)
09         return bestValue

10     else    (* minimizing player *)
11         bestValue := +∞
12         for each child of node
13             v := minimax(child, depth − 1, TRUE)
14             bestValue := min(bestValue, v)
15         return bestValue
```

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace minimax {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int total = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("the current total is " + total);

            while (total < 21) {
                Console.WriteLine("add 1 or 2?");
                total += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("you increased the total to " + total);
                if (total == 21) {
                    Console.WriteLine("you win");
                    break;
                }

                int bestMove = 1;
                int bestScore = 100;

                for (int i = 1; (i <= 2) && (total + i <= 21); i++) {
                    if (minimax(total + i, -1) < bestScore) bestMove = i;
                }

                total += bestMove;

                Console.WriteLine("computer increased the total to " + total);
                if (total == 21) {
                    Console.WriteLine("computer wins");
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int minimax(int total, int color) {
            if (total == 21) {
                return color * 100;
            }

            if (color == 1) {
                int bestValue = -100;

                int v = minimax(total + 1, -1);
                bestValue = max(bestValue, v);

                if (total < 20) {
                    v = minimax(total + 2, -1);
                    bestValue = max(bestValue, v);
                }

                return bestValue;
            }

            else {
                int bestValue = 100;

                int v = minimax(total + 1, 1);
                bestValue = min(bestValue, v);

                if (total < 20) {
                    v = minimax(total + 2, 1);
                    bestValue = min(bestValue, v);
                }

                return bestValue;
            }
        }

        static int max(int a, int b) {
            if (a > b) return a;
            return b;
        }

        static int min(int a, int b) {
            if (a < b) return a;
            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

The computer opponent is not making the right moves. When I trace through the code, it seems like the algorithm from the pseudocode is wrong.

For example if I skip to 17 at the start, the AI should increase the total by 1. Instead it increases it by two, which is a losing move.

Comment: I recognise the psedudocode from the Wikipedia entry on the Minimax algorithm which I am also using for the AI on a game I'm working on
It looks to me that your implementaion has totally skipped the part where you generate a decision tree for your game, which is basically a permutation of the game that you search through with the node parameter of the minimax function
Do a google search for "decision tree" and it should all fall into place; except maybe I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: That's not it. At any given node there are only two branches, +1 or +2. The issue was literally with a negative in the wrong place